# Add a Ref parameter in a "Binding Library"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

In my Binding library i have the following Method:
public static unsafe int ExportConfig (int p0)

I need to turn it to:
public static unsafe int ExportConfig (ref int p0)

I am trying to do that with Metadata.xml, but all i do make the compiler delete the method, anyway i can do that?

Comment: Post the api.xml that is generated for that method

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).